# Searching for specific value in array with while-loop

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I have the task to build a method to search for an identical value for a variable in an array.
When there is a match, the method will return the index-Position, otherwise it should return -1.

My method works when there is a match, but I get an error when there isn´t any match.

My Code so far:

```
public class Schleifentest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int [] cherry = {7,5,6,8,9};
        int magNumber = 112;
        int enthalten2 = Schleifentest.sucheWhile(cherry, magNumber);
        System.out.println(enthalten2);


    }

    public static int sucheWhile(int [] array, int a) {
        int i = 0;
        while(i <= array.length) { 
            if (array[i] == a) {
                return i;
            }
            i++;

        }
        // here is the problem
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Thanks  for your help.
Phil

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
while(i < array.length) {...}
```

suppose that the array has 10 elements. They are indexed from 0 to 9. When you reach the end, with your code, you'll consider the one indexed as 10, that doesn't exist, and you have the error.

Comment: that indexoutofbound through